# Wordpress menu css styling issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have developed basic html&css styled menu that i am now trying to change to wordpress menu. Problem here is from height fluctuation. Min-height has been set to 50px and in codepen it only expands to 55px height, it will in wordpress version expand to 65px height. Any styling help for this? 55px height still looks good but 65 is too much

```
#main-nav{
background: #2c2c2c;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 50px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2122;
z-index: 12;
}
#main-nav ul li {
text-transform: uppercase;
font-family: arial,Georgia, serif;
font-size:12px;
position: relative;
display: inline-block;
float: left;
border:1px solid #222222;
border-width:0 0 0 1px;
height:50px;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
display: inline-block;
height: 50px;
line-height: 50px;
color: #ddd;
padding:0 14px;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
border-left:1px solid #383838;
position: relative;}
```

http://codepen.io/reshogun/pen/rOVmrz

Comment: Instead of using min-height you can go for height

Answer (score 1):

You can either add a `max-height` of 55px or remove the `min-height` and give it a fixed `height` of 55px:

Using Max height: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQvONG)

```
#main-nav{
background: #2c2c2c;
margin: 0 auto;
min-height: 50px;
max-height: 55px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2122;
z-index: 12;
}
```

Using height: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BoNZao)

```
#main-nav{
background: #2c2c2c;
margin: 0 auto;
height: 55px;
border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2122;
z-index: 12;
}
```

Comment: It is shame that you need 10 rep to post img here. This max-height and height-setting breaks other css settings and forces. Menu-item is no longer centered vertically and because of that separator is over the nav background. Does anyone have idea what to do?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/zuVhlzO.png Here is link to how this menu is now after max-height / height setting

Comment: Here is wordpress/php code for that menu part:      <nav id="main-nav">
     <div class="container">
      <?php 
                $main_menu = array(
                'theme_location'   =>  'primary',
                'container_class'   => 'nav-menu-container',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav-menu',
              ); 
               wp_nav_menu($main_menu);
            ?>
        </div>
    </nav>

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your given link what you did in menu styling, and this not just because of you are using WordPress it is error of some miss use of css code. so below are the css changes you have to made and checkout it is working fine as you expected

```
body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 0 !important;
  height: 2999px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #454545;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 0;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
a {
  color: #1c1c1c;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #7ab80e;
  text-decoration: none;
}
ul,
ol {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 0 10px 25px;
}


#main-nav{
    background: #2c2c2c;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #cd2122;
    z-index: 12;
    position:relative;
}
#main-nav ul li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: arial,Georgia, serif;
  font-size:12px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border:1px solid #222222;
  border-width:0 0 0 1px;
  float:left;
}
#main-nav ul li a {
  display: inline-block;

  color: #ddd;
  padding:12px;
  text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
  border-left:1px solid #383838;
  position: relative;
}
```

Thanks
Sourabh

Comment: It is little better but still needs some fix. Separators should be from bottom to top. while it is not yet as you see it from picture. http://i.imgur.com/ETqyV8A.png

Comment: can i know why you are using the position:relative with every element

Comment: It seems "extra" ones are from my previous try to find solution on another problem. I will clean my css and post another version here

Comment: Please remove your css code and paste the following code that i have given  then let me know.

Comment: That 19 min ago posted img shows the problem it seems still have. Separator should vertically touch top

Comment: oh i think it is the problem of your side image css so fix it with folowing img{width:whatever you want;height:whatever you want} demo img{height:120px; width:200px}

Comment: Did some cleaning and now it seems to work right. I removed extra position declarations and noticed that my general settings had ul, ol declaration that was source of the problem. Fixed it now. Thanks sourabh for insight. It was helpful that had somebody to give input